# Custom URL Rewriting causing UpdatePanel Response Redirecting

Tags: asp.net

I have done custom url rewriting using IHTTPModule, but it cause update panel Response.redirect.

I googled some more times but got the solution is

```
form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;
```

and add `ScriptModule` in web config but these fix are not working in my case, but with out update panel all are working fine

My rewriting code is below

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.BeginRequest += (s, e) =>
    {
        var Application = s as HttpApplication;
        var PhysicalPath = Application.Request.PhysicalPath;
        if (!File.Exists(PhysicalPath) && !Path.HasExtension(PhysicalPath))
        {
            var argString = Application.Request.RawUrl.Replace("\\", "/").TrimStart('/');
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(argString))
            {
                Application.Context.RewritePath("/Default3.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Context.RewritePath("/Default2.aspx");
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides form1.Action = Request.RawUrl; 
You should also add the following line in your web.config as suggested by Ruslan Yakushev (http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewriting-for-aspnet-web-forms#Form_postback_URL).

Note the ".axd" line in "conditions" tag.

```
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <!--  The following condition prevents rule from rewriting requests to .axd files -->
    <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="article.aspx?p={R:1}" />
</rule>
```